# How to resolve [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable on OSX

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

Appcelerator LiveView is not connecting to the emulator/device on a new development laptop. The connection error occurs when tested with 2 different WiFi networks.

**The question is, how can I resolve/debug the [LiveView] File Server unavailable error message?**

```
"[LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 192.168.0.7:8324"

"[LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 127.0.0.1:8324"
```

I have tried the following:

- Clean the Project
- From a terminal, run killall node.
- Rerun the project
- Changing LiveView Host IP to 127.0.0.1
- Restart/Retry/Restart/Retry/BangHeadOnDesk

The only thing that seems suspicious is...

When requesting the IP:8324 from Safari on emulator I receive a quick JSON response. When requesting the IP:8323 from Safari on emulator I receive no reply in Safari but see `[LiveView] Client connected` in the Appcelerator console.

My Environment is:

- Mac OS X 10.13.1
- Node.js Version 8.9.1
- npm Version 5.5.1
- Titanium CLI Version 5.0.14
- Titanium SDK Version 6.3.0.GA
- Target Platform iPhone

Console display when running app"

```
[LiveView] version 1.2.1
[LiveView] Alloy project monitor started
[LiveView] File Server Started on 0.0.0.0:8324
[LiveView] Event Server Started on 0.0.0.0:8323
[INFO] :   KitchenSink/6.3.0 (6.3.0.3620088)
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 223;
[ERROR] :      line = 671;
[ERROR] :      message = "[LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 192.168.0.7:8324\n[LiveView] Please ensure your device and computer are on the same network and the port is not blocked.";
```

Comment: are your PC & devices connected to same WiFi network? This issue has always happened with me only when I had used different network connection on PC & testing device

Comment: Yes both on same network. And I am using OSX not a PC. I use LiveView often on an older laptop. Not connecting even using emulator which uses the host network adapter for the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED**

This issue has been resolved.

After setting up a new macbook I had imported [Kitchen Sink v2 sample app from the appcelerator GIT repo](https://github.com/appcelerator/kitchensink-v2) to get up and running. Liveview never worked but running without Liveview worked fine.

This morning I suspected the problem may be a Node installation / permissions issue and I tried [making the /usr/local directory writable by all](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Node-section-src-35620436_InstallingNode-Installation).

Still no luck and yes I did..clean the project, restart appcelerator, killall, etc.

Finally I just simply created a new alloy project and LiveView works just fine on new projects.

Must be a fluke I thought so I went back to Kitchen-v2 project...cleaned the project...compiled and ran with LiveView - *Still Not Working*.

***The issue appears to be (in my case) the Kitchen Sink v2 sample app.***

Comment: I think that app uses Hyperloop. You can't use that with Liveview.

Comment: Yep, hyperloop and liveview don't pair!

Comment: The kitchensink-v2 project does not use Hyperloop.